# Como receber uma informação em uma View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor, view

Programei meu *controller* da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string pUsuario, string pSenha)
{
     usuario oUsuario = modelOff.usuarios.Where(p => p.usuario1 == pUsuario && p.senha == pSenha).SingleOrDefault();
     if (oUsuario == null)
         return View("nao");
     else
         return View(oUsuario.usuario1);
}
```

Verifico se o usuário existe, se existir envia o nome dele pra *view*, se não existir, envia `nao`.

Quero saber como mostrar essa informação na *view*.

Minha *view*:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Olá Fulano</h2>
```

Comment: Como está sua *view*?

Comment: Está em branco, não sei como criá-la

Comment: Na verdade, tem apenas Olá Fulano (onde fulano seria o nome do usuário)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá,
Existem vários modos de passar dados pra View um deles é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`ViewBag` é uma variável que carrega informação para a `view`, e `Message` é uma chave onde voce ira colocar um valor, ou seja, pode criar outros nomes como nesse exemplo aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe também uma variável chamada `ViewData` que tem o mesmo propósito, essa é tipada como um dicionário contendo objetos, no exemplo abaixo podemos ver com mais detalhes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existem outros modos de passar dados, mas acho que esses que citei resolvem o seu problema.

Comment: Sria bom citar de onde pegou essas omagens: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/. Na verdade lá embaixo está escrito "©2017 C# Corner. All contents are copyright of their authors.", então nem pode pegá-las. Pode dar uma resposta sua onde de fonte que possa copiar?

Comment: Desculpa mas não tenho tempo, não nesses próximos dois meses. Então pode fazer o que quiser com essa resposta, pode ate deletar se quiser. O meu dever como membro da comunidade, de passar informação foi feito.

Answer (score 5):

Para o seu caso provavelmente uma simples *viewBag* deve servir:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string pUsuario, string pSenha) {
     usuario oUsuario = modelOff.usuarios.Where(p => p.usuario1 == pUsuario && p.senha == pSenha).SingleOrDefault();
     ViewBag.usuario = oUsuario == null ? "nao" : oUsuario.usuario1;
     return View();
}
```

View:

```
//precisa colocar onde está o modelo aqui, mas na pergunta não tem a localização
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Olá Fulano @ViewBag.usuario</h2>
```

Também pode fazer de outra forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string pUsuario, string pSenha) {
     usuario oUsuario = modelOff.usuarios.Where(p => p.usuario1 == pUsuario && p.senha == pSenha).SingleOrDefault();
     ViewBag.usuario = oUsuario == null ? "nao" : oUsuario.usuario1;
     return View((object)(oUsuario == null ? "nao" : oUsuario.usuario1));
}
```

View:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Olá Fulano @Model</h2>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ViewGettingData.cs).

Tem outras formas.